# Illustrator: is there a way to add area type with colored backgrounds to a library

Tags: adobe-illustrator, library

So I created a set of text boxes, that I styled with different colors, but the same paragraph style and area type options. I want to put these in a library so I can grab them and type identifications so I can use them as tab style labels on various projects.

When I try and add them to the library I get a notification about advanced type styles not being added and only adding the simple styles.

What's the best way to proceed? Is there a way I can make like a link to the master file to grab elements as I need them (I thought that was the purpose of the libraries)? Is there a workaround like making them symbols and then adding it?

Any help would be appreciated.

[image: The text boxes]

Comment: Hi! While the duplicate link above may not directly answer your question *specifically* regarding area type, it does provide a method of adding such a background to text, which can be saved as a style and to Libraries because it's a single object.

Comment: I'm having trouble saving the graphic styles to libraries, but thank you for the link.